# What are some open source social/collaboration solutions that could be integrated within an application?

Tags: open-source, java, software-development, collaboration, social-networks

We want an opensource solution that could provide us most of the social/collaboration features(commenting, sharing, liking etc on our data) and could be integrated with our architecture of the app(rest based services, few databases and a hybrid ionic app at the front-end).

We need to keep data at our servers so probably we would need a solution that we could setup locally within our infrastructure.

**Java would be preferred language.**

> Most of the solutions I found were to build social media websites but
>   we are looking for is something that could take data from us, model it
>   in whatever way necessary for the **solution** to be able to perform
>   all social operations on it and expose those operation via an api. So
>   by using this api I could ingest data into the **solutions** database
>   and and call necessary functions on it like comment,like,reply,share
>   etc and same I could sync it with my databases to perform operations
>   permitted by my application.

These are a few solutions I have explored but most of them felt in the first category i.e provided solutions for building social media websites:

- exoplatform, Elgg,  Oxwall, Dolphin and Buddypress

Note : I haven't done extensive research on all these solutions so If any of the above solution does satisfy my requirements and I have missed that then kindly share some resources on it.

Comment: Looks a bit broad to me. What "social items" do you have in mind? Note this site is for *specific* recommendations, not for "lists". So what tasks do you need to perform? What data should be "commented, shared, liked ***etc***", and what is "etc"? Which "social networks" must be supported? Before we can go and name you a software solution, we need the "problem to solve". Doesn't work the other way around here ("Here's the solution you can tailor your problem to" isn't the approach we take ;)

Comment: What "social items" do you have in mind? : Likes, Comments share etc.  What data should be "commented, shared, liked etc :  Our own data and obviously it would be some kind of a posts or anything that can be commented(think of comment etc as some operations that can be performed on data).  And i haven't asked for lists, What I have asked for is that if someone has already had similar requirement and have found a solution which they are already using. And I have only tried to explain a problem plus I have given some possible solutions that are very much similar but doesn't fit my use case.

Comment: I wasn't blaming you, just asking for clarification :) You might not have had a list in mind, but too general questions are provoking such. That's also why I asked for "what's 'etc'". May I ask you to [edit] your question accordingly, making clear what your must-have requirements are? Thanks in advance!